# How to make mayonnaise at home?

Tags: mayonnaise

I want to make sandwich with home maded mayonnaise. But I have no idea to make mayonnaise.How I can make mayonnaise at home?

Comment: Not for nothing but if you type that into your favorite search engine there are quite a number of recipes.

Comment: Not to be rude, but @steve is right, a better answer in this forum would be something like this: *"I am trying to make mayo at home using this recipe (link to recipe) but I do feel that the result is too thin. what can I do to to fix it?"*

Comment: Just a reminder: Recipe requests are off-topic here. Discussing methods or analyzing given recipes is ok.

Comment: Hint: If you have a food processor with an emulsion disk, use that for experimenting - these things can even make eggless mayonnaise easily :)

Answer (score 0):

mayo is easy to make at home, and I guess that [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how%20to%20make%20mayonnaise) would be more instructive than my humble explications, anyway:   mix egg yolk, then add a neutral oil (lige sunflower) little at a time, and I really mean just a 
trickle, very slowly, continue to mix with a whip. For an egg yolk (medium) you can add up to 250ml of oil. When it has a dense creamy texture, you can add salt, and lemon juice at your taste.
Some add mustard, vinegar, or pepper, but in my opinion the simpler the better.